# How to apply a special operator to a list?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

The following test is rejected:

```
CL-USER> (apply 'and '(t t t))
; Evaluation aborted on #<CCL::CALL-SPECIAL-OPERATOR-OR-MACRO #x3020013A1F3D>
```

My first reply was trying to encapsulate the call to the `and` special operator into a lambda or defining my own definition, but of course it can't work. Since it would results in calling the `apply` function for `'and` on the &rest parameter... How would you tackle the issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the function EVERY instead.

```
(every #'identity '(t t t))  -> t
```

You can't apply special operators.

Next solution:

```
(reduce (lambda (a b) (and a b))
        '(t t t)
        :initial-value t)
```

Don't use APPLY for list operations. Use REDUCE.

Comment: Sorry it seems it does not work ?
    CL-USER> (every 'and '(t) '(t))
    ; Evaluation aborted on #<CCL::CALL-SPECIAL-OPERATOR-OR-MACRO    #x30200133159D>. I put a -1 on that one since it does not work, as long as you don't provide a working example.

Comment: @yvesBaumes Try (every #'identity '(t t t)) <a href="http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_everyc.htm">CLHS has some documentation</a>.

Comment: @yves Baumes: EVERY requires a predicate of one argument per sequence.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I didn't get it first. I remove the -1 for a +1 and accepted your answer!  :-)

Comment: Also consider `(not (find nil list))` or `(not (member nil list))`. `find` works for vectors too.